# Split String in VB.Net but only if meets a certain format

Tags: vb.net, string, replace, split, format

I have the following code to split a string but it sometimes splits a word I do not intend to split.

For example it will split "LFMT" but I only want it to split a string with this format "FM123456".

The code is below;

```
Dim strSplitTAF() = New String() {"TEMPO", "PROB30", "PROB40", "BECMG", "FM"}

For Each strWord As String In strSplitTAF
    strTAF = strTAF.Replace(strWord, Environment.NewLine & strWord)
Next
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to split string with that Format for example: FM+(Numbers) or it is possible for that string to start with numbers?

Comment: It will always be FM followed by 6 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for the right format, use the following condition

```
    If Str1.Length = 8 AndAlso Str1.Substring(0, 2) = "FM" AndAlso IsNumeric(Str1.Substring(2, 6)) Then 
        'The code goes here
    End If
```

Replace the Str1 with the variable that has the format "FM123456"

**EDIT**

check if this is what you want

```
    'Test data for strTAF
    Dim strTAF As String = "TEMPO Test1 PROB30 Test2 PROB40 Test3 BECMG Test4 FM123456 Test5 LFMT Test6 FM654321 Test7 FM124"

    'FM is removed since it will use a specific condition to split the string (FM + 6 numbers)
    Dim strSplitTAF() = New String() {"TEMPO", "PROB30", "PROB40", "BECMG"}

    For Each strWord As String In strSplitTAF
        strTAF = strTAF.Replace(strWord, Environment.NewLine & strWord)
    Next

    'Removes the new line on the first line (optional)
    strTAF = strTAF.Trim

    'Finds the index of the first FM in the string
    Dim Index As Integer = strTAF.IndexOf("FM")

    While Index > -1
        'Checks if the index + 8 (FM + 6 numbers) exceeds the length of the strTAF
        If Index + 8 <= strTAF.Length Then
            'Checks if the string (consecutive 6 chars) after FM is numeric
            If IsNumeric(strTAF.Substring(Index + 2, 6)) Then
                strTAF = strTAF.Substring(0, Index) & Environment.NewLine & strTAF.Substring(Index)
            End If
        Else
            Exit While
        End If

        'Gets the new index of FM
        Index = strTAF.IndexOf("FM", Index + 8)
    End While
```